# How can I delay a block becoming visible in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a block of text (**h4**) become visible after a delay when the page loads.

Do I need to use `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to set some css animation:

```
h4 {
 animation: 1s fadeIn;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
 visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure JS and `setTimeout` this could be one solution.

```js
window.onload = event => {
  console.log("page is fully loaded");
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("delayed-3s").style.visibility = "visible";
  }, 3000);
};
```

```html
<h4 id="delayed-3s" style="visibility:hidden;">I am some h4 text</h4>
```